# Angular concatenating numbers instead of adding

Tags: angular

Angular typescript concatenating numbers instead of adding

**Class**

```
  title = 'app';

  a: number;
  b: number;

  c: number;

  calc(): void {
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
  }
```

**View**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="a" (keyup)="calc()">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="b" (keyup)="calc()">

<p>{{c}}</p>
```

**Return**

if `a = 1` and `b = 2` for example it equal `c = 12`, it should be `3` and when i try `parseInt(this.a)` it result error `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Comment: I think the problem is that you declare the properties as `number`, then what the typescript is saying make sense. Changing the type to string should solve that issue.

Comment: use the "+" to convert in number: `this.c=(+this.a)+(+this.b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use parseInt over number field, because it's already number.(However compiler thinks so).
But when you bind it to input with type text, it'll be converted into string. If you want to input only numbers you should use

```
<input type='number'>
```

This is how angular model binding works.

Comment: how is that happen angular should respect typescript rules ( variables types ) and parsed to number in background. because when i change type to number template design and css selectors will change also.

Comment: Yes, typescript respects variable types. But in runtime it's not typescript anymore, it's javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the input type you have mentioend the type as text. Change it to number and it should work fine.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a" (keyup)="calc()">
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b" (keyup)="calc()">

<p>{{c}}</p>
```

Also in the ts file initialize the values of a and b to 0, else you will see a NaN error while giving in input.

```
a: number =0;
  b: number=0;
```

Comment: how is that happen angular should respect typescript rules ( variables types ) and parsed to number in background. because when i change type to number template design and css selectors will change also.

Answer (score 1):

use the "+" to convert in number. In Angular, by defect, the input in an ngModel is a string

```
this.c=(+this.a)+(+this.b)
```

NOTE: you can use directly in the .html

```
{{+a+(+b)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
calc(): void {
    this.c = this.a + '' + this.b;
  }
```